# Swift - if string is nil. don't add it to the array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an `Array` of `Image` links -

```
let alamofireSource = [AlamofireSource(urlString: Img1!)!, AlamofireSource(urlString: Img2!)!,
AlamofireSource(urlString: Img3!)!, AlamofireSource(urlString: Img4!)!]
slideshow.setImageInputs(alamofireSource)
```

some posts have only one image or two or three, and so on. so, sometimes image 2 (for example) is nil, In that case, I don't want it to be added to the array, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ( **Swift 4** )

```
let arr = [img1,img2].compactMap{$0}.map{AlamofireSource(urlString:$0)!}
```

or

```
let arr = alamofireSource.compactMap{$0}
```

for **Swift 3**

```
let arr = alamofireSource.flatMap{$0}
```

Comment: Thanks a trillion! It fixed the problem :-)

Comment: This is Swift 4. You may want to add flatMap for Swift 3 or prior

Comment: @SophieBernard Note that the approach in this answer (forcibly unwrapping the result of the initializer) may lead to a run-time exception, as the `AlamofireSource(urlString:)` initializer is a failable initializer. I've added an answer below showing one approach to safely unwrap the result of the possibly failing initialization, taking also into account the fact that the url strings themselves (`Img1`, ... `Img4` in your example) are optionals, and should also be safely unwrapped.

Answer (score 1):

> so, sometimes image 2 (for example) is nil, In that case, I don't want
>   it to be added to the array, is that possible?

Yes it is. Although I would go with [Sh_Khan's suggestion](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150909/5501940) to use the `compactMap` method to achieve it, but it would be useless for your current case:

Based on your code snippet, I'd assume that `alamofireSource` of type `[AlamofireSource]`, but *not* `[AlamofireSource?]` and that's because you are *forcibly* unwrap its elements (by adding `!` to each of its elements). So far `alamofireSource` doesn't contain nils (actually it could be more danger than just a declaration, your app might crash!)

So first of all, I would recommend to remove the `!` from `alamofireSource`:

```
let alamofireSource = [AlamofireSource(urlString: Img1!),
                       AlamofireSource(urlString: Img2!),
                       AlamofireSource(urlString: Img3!),
                       AlamofireSource(urlString: Img4!)]
```

which means let it be as `[AlamofireSource?]`, therefore you would gain the benefit of using [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap):

> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given
>   transformation with each element of this sequence.

As:

```
let alamofireSourceWihoutNils = alamofireSource.compactMap { $0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put your `Optional` url strings into an array, say `urlStrings` (of type `[String?]`), you can construct `alamofireSource` according to (*Swift 4*):

```
let alamofireSource = urlStrings.compactMap { $0.map(AlamofireSource.init) }
```

Which make use of the [`map(_:)` operator of `Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) and [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) to unwrap the two-level optionality.

## Details

Your example contains two levels of optionality:

- The optional `ImgX` arguments of type `String?` - henceforth referred to and named as `img1`, ..., `img4`, as `CapitalFirstLetter` names are reserved for e.g. types, not type *instances*.
- The failable initilizer [`init?(urlString: String, placeholder: UIImage? = nil)` of `AlamofireSource`](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow/blob/0cbd12111cdb6239e926cc5c5bfea6c5379983ec/ImageSlideshow/Classes/InputSources/AlamofireSource.swift#L33).

First of all, lets gather the optional image links (`imgX`) into an array

```
let urlStrings = [url1, url2, url3, url4] // [String?]
```

#### Swift 4

You can combine the [`map(_:)` operator of `Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) with [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) to safely unwrap and make use of the `.some` entires of `urlStrings`, thereafter collect the successful invocations of the failable initializer of `AlamofireSource`:

```
let alamofireSource = urlStrings.compactMap { $0.map(AlamofireSource.init) }

// or, use a named closure argument
let alamofireSource = urlStrings.compactMap { str in str.map(AlamofireSource.init) }
```

#### Swift 3

If using Swift 3, replace the `compactMap(_:)` invocation above with [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2903427-flatmap):

```
let alamofireSource = urlStrings.flatMap { $0.map(AlamofireSource.init) }

// or, use a named closure argument
let alamofireSource = urlStrings.flatMap { str in str.map(AlamofireSource.init) }
```